# React breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a breadcrumb layout in my react project. I am not using router4 to render the URL.
At the moment the breadcrumbs appear like this.

```
Home
|Test Update
|Testssss
|Test11111
```

And i would like to have them all on one line.

```
home|Test Update|Testssss|Test11111
```

This is my code.

```
renderBreadCrumbs=(classes)=>{
    const {folderPathNames } = this.state;
    
    let items =[]
    if(!!folderPathNames){
      items = folderPathNames.map((folder,index)=>{
        return <div  key={index}>
        <a className={classes.rowalign} 
          onClick={this.handleFolderDestination}
          data-folder={folder.id}>|{folder.name}
        </a>
        </div>
      })
      return items
    }
  }
```

I tried to make all the components go to the same line by using the display-inline but it did not work.

```
  styles:
    rowalign:{
      display: 'inline-block'
    }
```

I also tried doing inline styling:

```
const divStyle = {
  display: 'inline-block'
};
```

and put that into my code on this line

```
<a style={divStyle} 
   onClick={this.handleFolderDestination}
   data-folder={folder.id}>
   {folder.name}
</a>
```

when i inspect the element in chrome i get

```
<a data-folder="206" style="display: inline-block;">|Testssss</a>
```

Can anyone tell me how to make the foldernames appear on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `style` props to apply inline styles, not `className` as per your code. Note `div` should be outside of all `a` as a container of them.

Write your code as:

```
renderBreadCrumbs=(classes)=>{
    const {folderPathNames } = this.state;

    let items =[]
    if(!!folderPathNames){
      items = folderPathNames.map((folder,index)=>{
        return ( 
        <a style={divStyle} 
           key={index}
           onClick={this.handleFolderDestination}
           data-folder={folder.id}>|{folder.name}
        </a>
        )
      })
      return <div>{items}</div>
    }
  }
```

Comment: i use a styling sheet for every one of the react components. Anyway if i use the styles the way you suggested that doesn't work either.

Comment: @GreatKhan2016 Open chrome devtool, and then check the html of those `a`, what do you see there? `style` attribute is present or not? What is styling sheet btw?

Comment: <a data-folder="194">.My chrome debugging skills are very limited. i have a seperate sheet on import into to the component. Probably the wrong word to be calling it a styling sheet.

Comment: Ok. so do you see now why it doesn't work.. style is not applied there... probably `classes.rowalign` is empty object `{}`.. add `console.log(classes)`.. What it prints there?

Comment: when i do console.log this has the rowalign:"Index-rowalign-500". maybe i should try and do an inline styling ?

Comment: Yes.. you can. But I don't understand from where `Index-rowalign-500` word comes... whatever.. I tried to show you how to debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180016/discussion-between-great-khan-2016-and-arup-rakshit).